# How can I implement AppCompatActivity in 2 fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm trying to add 2 fragment activities but I have to use AppCompatActivity. Because of that when I add AppCompatActivity the program stops. How can I solve this problem?

**My CombineFragmentActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Created by KHas on 29.04.2016.
 */
public class CombineFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.combine_fragment_activity);

        initialisePaging();


    }
    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,StartingTestActivity.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,ProfileActivity.class.getName()));
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

**My StartingTestActivity.java //First Fragment**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;


public class StartingTestActivity extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;



    public StartingTestActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static StartingTestActivity newInstance() {
        StartingTestActivity fragment = new StartingTestActivity();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_startingtest, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-MI.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_L = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-L.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_R = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-R.ttf");

        TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        info.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);
        question.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);


        // Get the ActionBar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();


        // Create a TextView programmatically.
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        // Create a LayoutParams for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView

        // Apply the layout parameters to TextView widget
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set text to display in TextView
        // This will set the ActionBar title text
        tv.setText("Anasayfa");

        // Set the text color of TextView
        // This will change the ActionBar title text color
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF5EE"));

        // Center align the ActionBar title
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the serif font for TextView text
        // This will change ActionBar title text font
        tv.setTypeface(ubuntu_MI);

        // Underline the ActionBar title text
        // tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        // Set the ActionBar title font size
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,24);

        // Display a shadow around ActionBar title text
        //tv.setShadowLayer(
        //      1.f, // radius
        //    2.0f, // dx
        //  2.0f, // dy
        //  Color.parseColor("#FF8C00") // shadow color
        //);

        // Set the ActionBar display option
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Finally, set the newly created TextView as ActionBar custom view
        ab.setCustomView(tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
                break;
            case 1:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
                break;
            case 2:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**My ProfileActivity.java // Second Fragment**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProfileActivity extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public ProfileActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static ProfileActivity newInstance() {
        ProfileActivity fragment = new ProfileActivity();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-MI.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_L = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-L.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_R = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-R.ttf");

        TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        info.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);
        question.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);


        // Get the ActionBar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();


        // Create a TextView programmatically.
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        // Create a LayoutParams for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView

        // Apply the layout parameters to TextView widget
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set text to display in TextView
        // This will set the ActionBar title text
        tv.setText("Anasayfa");

        // Set the text color of TextView
        // This will change the ActionBar title text color
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF5EE"));

        // Center align the ActionBar title
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the serif font for TextView text
        // This will change ActionBar title text font
        tv.setTypeface(ubuntu_MI);

        // Underline the ActionBar title text
        // tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        // Set the ActionBar title font size
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,24);

        // Display a shadow around ActionBar title text
        //tv.setShadowLayer(
        //      1.f, // radius
        //    2.0f, // dx
        //  2.0f, // dy
        //  Color.parseColor("#FF8C00") // shadow color
        //);

        // Set the ActionBar display option
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Finally, set the newly created TextView as ActionBar custom view
        ab.setCustomView(tv);
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Action Bar' daki settings kısmına basıldığında ne yapacağını söylüyoruz.
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ayarlara basıldı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_activity, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    private MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

}
```

**combine_fragment_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

**ERROR**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: You add Fragments to Activities. You don't implement Fragments as Activities or Activities in Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`ProfileActivity` should extend `Fragment`, not `AppCompatActivity`, like `StartingTestActivity` does.

Also I'd recommend renaming them to something less confusing. Like `ProfileFragment` and `StartingTestFragment`.

Comment: I edited my codes. Can you take a look at them? Still program stops. Where are the mistakes?

Comment: Can you also add the `activity_main` layout? It seems there isn't a view with the `viewpager` id in there, causing `pager` to be `null`.

Comment: activity_main layout or combine_fragment_activity ? If you mean combine_fragment_activity, I haven't it, I don't know why. Should I include? because in activity_profile, I have viewpager there.

Comment: `CombineFragmentActivity` is using `activity_main` as it is. See the line: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Yes you're right. Should I delete it or should I add a layout?

Comment: You need a layout specific to your activity that displays what you need it to display.

Comment: I edit setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); as setContentView(R.layout.combine_fragment_activity); and I edited my combine_fragment_activity.xml in the question part up there.